# How to keep an external exe file running after it was opened in VB6?

Tags: winapi, vb6, exe

I have a `VB6` program from which I open an external `exe` file. I use `Shell Execute` function which looks like this

```vb
Private Declare Function ShellExecute _
                          Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" _
                              (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, _
                               ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, _
                               ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long
```

and `SetParent` function which looks like this

```vb
Private Declare Function SetParent _
                          Lib "user32" (ByVal hWndChild As Long, _
                                        ByVal hWndNewParent As Long) As Long
```

The `exe` file is opened and attaced to the `VB6` form when I call `SetParent` function, but I would like to keep the `exe` file opened in `VB6` form and opened separate as a stand alone.

This is how I call `ShellExecute` and `SetParent`

```vb
ShellExecute Me.fraImage.hwnd, vbNullString, FilePath, "", vbNullString, 1
SetParent BlackmagicHandle, Me.fraImage.hwnd
```

Any idea how to keep the `exe` file running?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run the external program as a standalone you can try using shell in place of shellexecute. For example in the code of a button click on a VB6 form, the line :

```
shell "calc.exe"
```

launch the calculator that will stay open when VB program is closed.

Comment: I've tried with `Shell "calc.exe"` but it is the same, `SetParent BlackmagicHandle, Me.fraImage.hwnd` is integrating the `exe` file into `VB6` form and close the stand alone `exe`.

Comment: But why do you need to use setParent, if you want to keep it standalone ?

Comment: The `exe` file is a live stream from a capture card, and when I press a button to save a picture, the `textbox` from the form counts the number of saved pictures. Everything till now works fine. I move forword in my application and if I go back to the live stream form, the number of saved pictures resets to 0, because the `exe` file is re-opened. I wanted to keep it open continuously so it keeps the count alive.

Comment: @s_diaconu are you sure the exe process is being terminated? Is your app creating a second one, perhaps, instead?

Comment: @DaveInCaz the exe is still running, but inside the VB6 form, not as a stand alone. If I take of `SetParent` the exe is running as stand alone, but the issue is that it gets maximized and is on top of the VB6 form. The question is if there is any way that it can run as stand alone behind the VB6 and in the same time inside the VB6.

Comment: Call `setparent` and set it to the desktop window when you want to detach from VB6 app.